# Изменение размера и бэкграунда div при наведении мышкой

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Всё бы ничего, но див сидит среди других дивов в одном ряду. Т.е. имеем, скажем, 5 div-ов. Наводишь на 2й слева мышкой - поменялась картинка и его ширина изменилась таким образом, чтобы сдвинуть остальные 3 справа в сторону.
 Я использую это:

```
.div1 { 
    background: url(/img/1.png) no-repeat;  
    width: 100px; 
    height: 400px; 
}
.div1:hover { 
    background: url(/img/8.png) no-repeat;
    width: 300px;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
} 

<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
<div class="div4"></div>
<div class="div5"></div>
```

И идёт у меня 5 дивов. Cтили, соответственно, для каждого прописаны. Но все дивы выстраиваются друг под другом. Если назначить им {  float: left;} то они становятся так, как нужно, но! перестаёт работать смента картинок и изменение размера. Как допилить?
 И как можно добавить в ту часть, которая появляется из-за увеличения ширины дива - всплывающий текст?

Comment: посмотри flex-box http://habrahabr.ru/post/257253/, возможно это тебе поможет.      
если ссылка будет не действительна- то " указать здесь самое главное" уже небудет иметь смысла, потому ка уточнить уже негде будет. хотя самое главное уже указано: flex-box.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

От добавления `float: left` ничего сломаться не должно.
Смотрите пример http://jsfiddle.net/y9hqdzpd/

```
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

css

```
.item{width: 100px; height: 200px; background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/Aurora_as_seen_by_IMAGE.PNG'); transition-duration: 0.5s; float: left;}

.item:hover{width: 200px; background: url('http://www.thinkstockphotos.co.uk/CMS/StaticContent/Hero/TS_AnonHP_462882495_01.jpg');}
```

и сравнивайте со своим кодом. Возможно, у вас прописано что-то еще.